# Height and margin of #fav-tip are incorrect when clicking "add to favorites" on Stack Overflow Careers when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

When clicking "add to favorites" for a job on Stack Overflow Careers when you are not logged in the styling is incorrect on the #fav-tip element.

Here's what appears currently:

[image: Current display]

I don't know exactly what this is supposed to look like, but I think this can be fixed by changing the height of #fav-tip and the margin-bottom of the paragraph within #fav-tip. I removed the "height: 46px" from #fav-tip and added a "margin-bottom: 0" to the p tag within #fav-tip and got this result:

[image]

I'm not sure if that's exactly right, but it seems better than the current display.

For the sake of clarity, this occurred for me in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report and the suggested changes. They worked like a charm.

Fixed.